# Stored Procedures Return Mysql Php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure in mysql, which does an insert into a table and the selects a field(id), so that it later be assigned to a php variable, to eventually pass it as a parameter to another mysql procedure. The first procedure works fine when I call it from mysql, it returns the value it was meant to. The problem lays on when I try to obtain that value from php.
Heres my code:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE addEntity(p_idPerson INT(11),
p_nameP VARCHAR(50), p_objective VARCHAR(8),
OUT p_idProduct INT(11)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO EntityTb (idPerson, nameP, objective) VALUES(p_idPerson, p_nameP, p_objective);
SET p_idProduct= (SELECT idProduct FROM EntityTb WHERE idPerson= p_idPerson ORDER BY idProduct DESC LIMIT 1);
SELECT p_idProduct;
END$
DELIMITER;
```

PHP

```
$prep_stmt = "CALL addEntity(?,?,?,?)";
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
$p_id= "@p_idProduct";

if ($insert_stmt) { 
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('issi', $arg1, $arg2, $arg3 $p_id);
    $insert_stmt->execute();
    while ($rs= $insert_stmt->fetch()) {
        //debug($rs);
        echo "\r\n rs: ".$rs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just had to change the php code above to the one below.

$insert_stmt= $mysqli->query("CALL addProduct($arg1, '$arg2', '$arg3', @p_idProduct)");

```
if ($insert_stmt->field_count)
{   
    $rs= $insert_stmt->fetch_assoc();
    $id_prod= $rs['p_idProduct'];
    echo "id_product: ".$id_product;
}
```